# How to close a Dialog created with OfficeRuntime.displayWebDialog from Excel desktop?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-addins

In a custom function for Excel (desktop) add-in, I am opening a dialog using `OfficeRuntime.displayWebDialog` and after getting the information I need, the dialog should close.

I discovered that I can't use the `Office.context.ui.messageParent` with Excel desktop, so I need to send the data through `OfficeRuntime.storage.setItem`.

But, how the dialog will close itself after storing the value? Does it have any reference to itself so it can call `<dialog object>.close`? `window.close()` does not work.